# EC2 Instance status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

If I have a thousands of server's running in AWS, how can i get the list of servers that are in running state and the ones in stopped state.

Comment: You can use amazon aws cli https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS CLI tool as below

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

More details in the link below
https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: Thanks for your time and quick response

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instance-state-name` filter as a part of `describe-instances` call and set it value to `stopped` to obtain all the instances that are stopped.

```
--filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped"
```

if you want to reduce the amount of received data then you can query only for subset of instances' attributes such as, instance-id and state.

```
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,State:State.Name}'
```

Then full command becomes

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,State:State.Name}'
```